# How do I go about using a parameter/function of a specific child object after I've checked if it's the child and not the parent?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a system for a game where I have a class called Scene which stores things like GameObjects. I've made a child class called GameScene which also stores level, a list of integers, and Player. On top of that, I have a static object that stores the currently existing scene.

Now I want to make an in-game debugger that:

1. Checks if the current scene is a GameScene
2. If that is true, displays some info on velocity of the Player etc.

This poses a problem, however, because after I check if the current scene is a GameplayScene, I still have to convince the compiler of the fact that I'm dealing with a GameplayScene, and not just any old Scene. How do I go about doing that?

I assume (and hope) it's an anticlimactically easy answer and I just didn't find the right terms for it.

This is what I was thinking to do.

```
if (InputManager.doLevelStuff && SceneManager.currentScene is GameScene)
    SceneManager.currentScene.level.DoLevelStuff();
}
```

Of course that gives an error, as Scene does not contain a definition for level.

Comment: I didn't know you could use parentheses to cast specific parts like that. I think this might be it!  


EDIT: It works. Thank you so very much!  


As to the context, it was more of a general question, as it's a problem I can see myself facing in many different ways in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow you but in order to invoke methods of a derive type using IS is not enough you need to cast to the specific class
((GameScene)SceneManager.currentScene.level).DoLevelStuff()
Better approach will be to use as
And check for null

Comment: That works! While someone ninja'd you in the comments, I'm thankful for your answer!